# How to get client information in every IdentityServer4 api calls? (for logging purpose)

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-core-webapi, identityserver4

I have an api protected by identityServer4:

```
   services.AddAuthentication(defaultScheme: IdentityServerAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
        .AddIdentityServerAuthentication(options =>
        {
            options.Authority = "https://localhost:5000";
            options.ApiName = "api1";
            options.ApiSecret = "secret";

            options.EnableCaching = true;
            options.CacheDuration = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(10); // that's the default
        });

    // adds an authorization policy to make sure the token is for scope 'api1'
    services.AddAuthorization(options =>
    {
        // some policies here
    });
```

I want to log **every** client's api **call** (**not just the authentication**) with the client information like : `ClientId, ClientName, ...`.
here is my interceptor middleware:

```
public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env, ILogger logger)
{
    app.UseHttpsRedirection();
            
    app.Use(async (context, next) =>
    {                
        // Log the incoming request here (e.g clientId, clientName, ...)
        await next.Invoke();
     });

     // ...
}
```

how can I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up with catching OAuth2 events :

```
options.OAuth2IntrospectionEvents.OnTokenValidated = async (context) =>
{
   var identity = context.Principal.Identity as ClaimsIdentity;
   identity.AddClaim(new Claim("my_claim", "claim_value"));
   // ...
   // log the request   
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add the Serilog ASP.NET Core [NuGet package](https://github.com/serilog/serilog-aspnetcore) to get all the details logged.

Then also use the SerilogRequestLogging middleware:

```
// Write streamlined request completion events, instead of the more verbose ones from the framework.
// To use the default framework request logging instead, remove this line and set the "Microsoft"
// level in appsettings.json to "Information".
app.UseSerilogRequestLogging();
```

See sameple code [here](https://github.com/serilog/serilog-aspnetcore/blob/dev/samples/EarlyInitializationSample/Startup.cs)

Comment: No. I don't have problem with logging frameworks like NLog, Serilog,... . I want to intercept IS4 api calls.