# How to get Client Info inside API Method for Identity Server 4

Tags: c#, api, .net-core, identityserver4

I have a project in Identity server 4 where I have a create method in middleware application so I wants to set some default value based on Client invoking APIs (may be client name)

Scenario, We have a API endpoint for Register User that will be invoke by multiple clients using separate client Ids and Client name like "MobileAPP", "Website" and "CRMAPP"

I wants to add some default value based on client who is invoking that "register user" API.

Can suggestion or clue is appreciated to achieve this.

I tried to read request context but did not found anything. I found a way to logs based on clients defined [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63307102/how-to-get-client-information-in-every-identityserver4-api-calls-for-logging-p) but not client info in our API methods.

**Client Definition**:

```
new Client
            {
                ClientName = "Test Mobile App",
                ClientId = "test_mobile_app",
                AllowedGrantTypes = GrantTypes.ClientCredentials,
                ClientSecrets =
                    {
                        new Secret("mykey".Sha256())
                    },
                AllowedScopes =
                    {
                        "app.openid",
                        "app.profile",
                        "user.manage"
                    },
                AllowOfflineAccess = true,
                RefreshTokenUsage = TokenUsage.ReUse,
                AccessTokenLifetime = 3600,
                RefreshTokenExpiration = TokenExpiration.Absolute,
                AbsoluteRefreshTokenLifetime = 2592000
            }
```

**Policy:**

```
 option.AddPolicy("MobileAppScope", policy =>
            {
                policy.RequireAuthenticatedUser();
                policy.RequireClaim("scope", "user.manage")
                .RequireClaim("scope", "app.openid")
                .RequireClaim("scope", "app.profile");

            });
```

Authorization Attribute:

```
 [Authorize(Policy = "MobileAppScope", AuthenticationSchemes = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When the users log in from a specific client, you can [add claims](https://docs.duendesoftware.com/identityserver/v5/fundamentals/claims/) so you can add another claim containing the clientId:

```
 public virtual Task GetProfileDataAsync(ProfileDataRequestContext context)
 {
    var requestedClaimTypes = context.RequestedClaimTypes;
    var user = context.Subject;

    // your implementation to retrieve the requested information
    var claims = GetRequestedClaims(user, requestedClaimsTypes);
    //Here add a claim for ClientId
    claims.Add(new Claim("ClientId", context.Client.ClientId));
    context.IssuedClaims.AddRange(claims);

    return Task.CompletedTask;
 }
```

When the user is not authenticated yet you can decode the jwt token and get the client id in the body of the API method like this:

```
var token=(new JwtSecurityTokenHandler()).ReadJwtToken([tokenFromHeader]);
```

Comment: Claims could be used after user is loggedIn but in my scenario we are registering and no one is loggedin.

Just App is invoking using Authorization token created using client ID and Client Secret

Comment: By default no authorization token is present when user is not logged in. Have you any authentication mechanism for calling that Api endpoint? If the answer is yes so put it here and see if we are able to use it for the purpose. If the answer is no, finding the caller of the end point in Identity Server has no difference with other endpoints.  You can just rely on the general attributes such as IP.

Comment: Yes, I have authorization mechanism based on policy.

Client App will first invoke Identity Server endpoint (/connect/token) to get token and that would be used to authorize invocation of API

Comment: I have added client definition example above that I am using.

Comment: So you have the jwt token in the header of the request in the Api right?

Comment: If so why not just decode the token? It always have clientId in it. Just decode it like this:
(new JwtSecurityTokenHandler()).ReadJwtToken([tokenFromHeader]);

Comment: Thanks MD Zand, this could be a good option in my scenario.